# Attaching click event to certain links within a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have navigation divs with a number of links to both internal content and external pages.  We are creating a vanilla javascript to intercept any clicks, determine the content required and insert it in the page, rather than reloading the entirety of the page everytime.

Creating a script that uses a click event listener on the parent div worked superficially, fetching and inserting if you clicked on <a>, but also captured click events on any other text in the menu (titles and such) which subsequently failed:

```
 $('#navfly').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   var newpg = e.target.getAttribute('href');
   // take href value, modify url for content location
   // fetch content with ajax GET
   // insert within content div
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

The nav div concept:

```
 <div id="navfly">
 <a href="content-one.htm">Content 1</a><br>
 <a href="content-two.htm">Content 2</a><br>
 <a href="content-three.htm">Content 3</a><br>
 <a href="content-four.htm">Content 4</a><br>
 <a href="https://some.otherdomain.com">External wepage</a><br>
 </div>
```

I am looking for a way to target <a> within a specific div.  In addition I need to be able to ignore clicks on some links and allow them to function as normals links.

And contrary to my use of $( ) in the script, I am using vanilla javascript, NOT Jquery.  Just using a Jquery like querySelector function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to handle just the `a` tags you want:

```js
var navFly = document.querySelector('#navfly');

navFly.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // if it's not an a tag, that doesn't start with http do nothing
  if (!e.target.matches('a:not([href^="http"])')) {
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();

  var newpg = e.target.getAttribute('href');
  
  console.log(newpg);
  // take href value, modify url for content location
  // fetch content with ajax GET
  // insert within content div
});
```

```html
<div id="navfly">
  <a href="content-one.htm">Content 1</a><br>
  <a href="content-two.htm">Content 2</a><br>
  <a href="content-three.htm">Content 3</a><br>
  <a href="content-four.htm">Content 4</a><br>
  <a href="https://some.otherdomain.com">External wepage</a><br>
</div>
```